# I want to display firestore array in a ListView.builder

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an array called "Names" in the firestore. i want to display that array elements in a ListView.builder. i tried many ways but could not do it. i don't know how to access snapshot data.

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: getList(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Center(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                   snapshot.data[0].data), //snapshot data should dispaly in this text field
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
```

this is my getList() method.

```
 Future<List<dynamic>> getList() async {
var firestore = Firestore.instance;

DocumentReference docRef =
    firestore.collection('RecodeBook').document('2019-05-04');
List<dynamic> info = new List<String>();
docRef.get().then((datasnapshot) {
  if (datasnapshot.exists) {
    info = datasnapshot.data['Names'].toList();
    print('#');
    print(info); //this line prints [aa, aghshs, fffg, fug, ghh, fggg, ghhh]
    print(info.length); //this line prints 7
  }
});
return info;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be because you are sending back a `List<dynamic>` and not a `Future<List<dynamic>>`. The following code should work

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getList() async {
  var firestore = Firestore.instance;

  DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection('RecodeBook').document('2019-05-04');

  return docRef.get().then((datasnapshot) {
    if (datasnapshot.exists) {
      List<dynamic> info = datasnapshot.data['Names'].toList();
      print('#');
      print(info); //this line prints [aa, aghshs, fffg, fug, ghh, fggg, ghhh]
      print(info.length); //this line prints 7
      return info;
    }
  });
}
```

Also, in your `ListView.builder` do take note of the index.

```
title: Text(
  snapshot.data[index].data), //snapshot data should display in this text field
```

Comment: thank you. your getList() function worked. and i edited Text as
    title: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
then it worked.